Linear Regression on groupby Pandas DataFrame
Currently I have my code set up like this:
def lregression(data, X, y):
    X = df['sales'].values.reshape(-1, 1)
    y = df['target']
    model = LinearRegression()
    result = model.fit(X, y)
    return model.score(X, y)

Then, I'm trying to apply this model per brand:
df.groupby('brand').apply(lregression, X, y)

But the result just gets applied to the full dataset:
Brand A    0.734
Brand B    0.734
Brand C    0.734

Am I missing something here?  I want the model to run separately for each group, but instead I'm apparently getting the model applied to the full dataset and then having the overall score returned for each group.  Thanks!

You need to give more information about the dataset you are using

So far, by the given example, I can understand that you want to query all entries for a brand and fit a regressor on top of it. One way is to get all unique brand names, then query their data individually - train a model, and save the model with brand name

The dataset is just predicting the target variable using sales, and I would like to have the regression scored per group instead of at the overall level.  I know there's a way to do it similar to this, but I just haven't been able to get the result.

DATAFRAME
A minimal reproducible example is always nice to have, I'll provide it here:
np.random.seed(42)
data = {
    'brand': np.random.choice(['Brand A', 'Brand B', 'Brand C'], size=300),
    'sales': np.random.randint(100, 1000, size=300),
    'target': np.random.randint(100, 1000, size=300)
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

FUNCTION
To me it's not clear whether you want to return the score (namely R^2) or the coef of the single regressions, in both cases the function changes only slightly:

Score

def lregression(group):
    X = group['sales'].values.reshape(-1, 1)
    y = group['target']
    model = LinearRegression()
    result = model.fit(X, y)
    return result.score(X, y)


Coefficients

def lregression(group):
    X = group['sales'].values.reshape(-1, 1)
    y = group['target']
    model = LinearRegression()
    result = model.fit(X, y)
    return result.coef_

Then the final step (coef_ scenario):
>>> df.groupby('brand').apply(lregression)
 
brand
Brand A     [0.20322970187699263]
Brand B     [0.09134770152569331]
Brand C    [0.043343302335992005]
dtype: object

Which works as expected

Understood on the example for next time, thanks so much! I was able to use this to get it to work, I was just confused on how my function should work I think.
